# Close Navigation Drawer on Back Button Pressed in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, material-design

I have a material designed Navigation Drawer in my very first flutter app. This work's fine but I did't find any way to close the Navigation Drawer on Back Button Press if it's open when use `WillPopScope` to show `AlertDialog`. The application just show `AlertDialog` instead of close the Drawer when back press. I want Drawer should close if already open and show `AlertDialog` otherwise.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: onBackPressed,
    child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Home"),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Home"),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

**onBackPressed** shows dialog to close the app.

```
Future<bool> onBackPressed() {
  return showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: false,
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
            title: Text("Do you want to exit?"),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
                  child: Text("No")),
              FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, true),
                  child: Text("Yes"))
            ],
          ));
}
```

Can anybody guide me how can I achieve this?

Comment: I copy/paste your code and it's working fine. When I press back button it close the Drawer

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: You need Scaffold key to controll Drawer so you need `GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _key = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();` 
Step 2: In `onWillPop` You can check `isDrawerOpen` and do `Navigator.pop`

code snippet

```
 GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _key = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        if (_key.currentState.isDrawerOpen) {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        print("My App Page");
        //return false;
      },
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: MyHomePage(title: "test",),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _key = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        if (_key.currentState.isDrawerOpen) {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        key: _key,
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text(title)),
        body: Center(child: Text('My Page!')),
        drawer: Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: <Widget>[
              DrawerHeader(
                child: Text('Drawer Header'),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text('page 2'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                      context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page2()));
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text('Item 2'),
                onTap: () {
                  // Update the state of the app
                  // ...
                  // Then close the drawer
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        print("Page2");
        _popNavigationWithResult(context, 'from_back');
        return false;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _popNavigationWithResult(context, 'from_button');
          },
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Text('Page 2',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _popNavigationWithResult(BuildContext context, dynamic result) {
    Navigator.pop(context, result);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate instead of just code and also guide me how can I use it with `AlertDialog` as I asked in question? Thanks

Comment: do you mean when click device back button , show AlertDialog to ask user does he want to close drawer? or close drawer directly and show AlertDialog to ask user does he want to leave?

Comment: No, If Drawer is open then it should close on back press and don't show dialog. Dialog shows otherwise

Comment: do you see my posted animated gif? can you refresh your page.

Answer (score 0):

my Back button was not working on drawer, because of my home screen. Remove WillPopScope from drawer and put following code in the home screen instead.

```
WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () async {
    return Navigator.of(context).canPop();
  },
  child: Scaffold(
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply add Navigator.pop(context);

```
ListTile(
  title: const Text('Item 1'),
  onTap: () {
    // Update the state of the app
    // ...
    // Then close the drawer
    Navigator.pop(context);
  },
),
```