# Close side drawer when user comes back to home screen (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, onbackpressed

In side drawer created by me, when user clicks on any link, user goes to that screen and drawer closes as well, no issues with that, also when user opens side drawer and press back key, drawer closes, this is also working.

However, suppose user clicked on 'My Profile' link (or any link), and if then user presses back key from the profile screen to go back to home screen (or uses back key in appbar), user finds side drawer opened on home screen. Then either user has to press back key or tap anywhere on the screen to close drawer.

Initially, my drawer was not closing on back-press even, I found this post [https://stackoverflow.com/q/60314156] and implemented **WillPopScope()** [Actually that helped me to close drawer on backpress], however the issue which I have explained, is still unresolved with WillPopScope.

Kindly let me know what changes I have to do to implement this behavior.

This is how I have created files : HomePage which has BottomNavigationDrawer through which user comes to shopping page (which is labeled as 'Home' actually), and this is the page where user see side drawer. So above while explaining when I said home, I meant Shopping Page from where user navigated to profile page.

```
class ShoppingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ShoppingPageState createState() => _ShoppingPageState();
}

class _ShoppingPageState extends State<ShoppingPage> {
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _key = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ThemeData getTheme = Theme.of(context);
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        if (_key.currentState.isDrawerOpen) {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        key: _key,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: ,
          elevation: 0,
        ),
        drawer: CustomDrawer(),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share drawer code where you are pushing to another screen?

Comment: Navigator.popAndPushNamed is your answer https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/popAndPushNamed.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you simply call :-

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

before navigating to another screen from drawer. Like when user clicks on your profile then in onTap method first pop it then navigate.

```
onTap:(){
Navigator.pop(context);
//then write navigation statement over here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because the Navigation Drawer is still in the stack of pages.
When the user navigates to another screen using a link it adds the new screen to the stack.

Your attempt:

```
WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        if (_key.currentState.isDrawerOpen) {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
          return false;
        }
```

closes the Navigation Drawer, if it is open, when the user presses the back button while on the Shopping Screen.

You need to remove the Navigation Drawer from the stack before navigating to the next screen. You can do that by adding

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

before the navigation logic.

You can also try

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(context, <newRoute>)
```

To replace the Navigation Drawer with the new screen, which will also give the same result.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts for the way you explained the underlying concept of how stack is working and why exactly we need to use pop here, however being beginner, I got little lost and confused midway answer.